# split epimorphims and direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ and $N$ be modules and $f : M \to N $ a split surjection (that is there exists a map $g : N \to M$ such that $f\circ g=id_N$). Then can we write

$$ M \simeq Ker(f) \oplus Im(f) \ \text{?}$$

Please help me.

Comment: Write an element $m \in M$ as $m = gf(m) + (m - gf(m))$. Note that $im(f) = N$, and that $g$ is injective.

Comment: So you wrote $M=(gf)M \oplus (1-gf)M$ this follows because gf is idempotent. From this how the result follows?

Comment: The first term can be identified with $N$, and the latter with $ker f$ (its clear that $ker f \supset (1 - gf)M$, so prove the other direction by showing that any $m$ so that $f(m) = 0$ has $(1 - gf)m' = m$ for some $m$)

Comment: that m' can be m itself right? Because if $f(m)=0$ then $gf(m)=0$ and we can write $m=m-gf(m)$ and so $m \in (1-gf)M$ so $kerf $is contained in $(1-gf)M$.

Comment: Yeah exactly. :)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337837/relation-of-r-module-homomorphisms-with-direct-sums?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence $$0\longrightarrow Ker(f)\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow N\longrightarrow0.$$
Note that $(g\circ f)²=(g\circ f)\circ(g\circ f)=g\circ(f\circ g)\circ f=g\circ f$ and $Ker(g\circ f)=Ker(f)$ (because $g$ is injective; check it!). Therefore $g\circ f$ is a projection of $M$. Then $$M=Im(g\circ f)\oplus Ker(g\circ f)=Im(g\circ f)\oplus Ker(f).$$ Since $$Im(f)\simeq\frac{M}{Ker(f)}\simeq Im(g\circ f)$$ the result follows.

Comment: What do you mean that $g\circ f$ is a projection of $M$? How does the next line follow from what you wrote?

Comment: @Nex, a projection of M is an endomorphism e of M such that $e²=e$. So, you can see that, if $1$ is the identity map of $M$, $1-e$ is idenpotent and $M=e(M)\oplus(1-e)(M)$. You can see also that $(1-e)(M)=Ker(e)$.

Comment: Okay rather than in the sense of projection from a product. I thought one would call such a homomorphism an idempotent. Furthermore, to me this seems to be an upside-down way of thinking about it. The basic facts here and in any abelian category seem to me to be that every split epimorphism is (up to isomorphism) a biproduct projection and dually every split monomorphism is (up to isomorphism) a biproduct inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Check  the splitting lemma over here . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma
here the exact sequence is $0 \rightarrow kerf \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow0$

Comment: Yes you are right.. Thank you :)